# Employing optimal packing, how many circles (51 mm diameter) can I cut from a rectangle (330 mm×530 mm)

Tags: geometry, packing-problem, tessellations

I know that I should use some kind of honeycomb structure but can't work out in which orientation I should arrange it. I've looked at a few websites now and although I have a slightly better idea of the options, I can't work out how to model the problem and therefore calculate how many circles I could cut.

Specifically I would like to know:

~ How could I model this and what mathematics are involved?

~ What is the maximum number of 51 mm-diameter circles I can cut from a 330 mm × 530 mm rectangle?

~ What is the minimum size rectangle from which I could cut 16 circles?

(As you might suspect this is a real-life problem that I must solve, the disks that I will cut are to be used in a physics experiment but the material from which they are made is very expensive. It can however be purchased in any size rectangle, up to 330 mm × 530 mm.)

*EDIT*

OK so I just discovered this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701/how-many-circles-of-a-given-radius-can-be-packed-into-a-given-rectangular-box)) and the Wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square) contained therein. Whilst it is certainly related I am no closer to solving my current queries. (Other than if I were to order a square sheet of the material measuring 204 mm × 204 mm but I'm sure a rectangle would be more efficient.)

Comment: In the title, and once in the text, you say that the long edge is 530 mm; but later you say 550 mm.

Comment: Right you are @John, I'll correct the typo, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your problem, one choice is to order a rectangle with both dimensions a multiple of 51 mm, use a square pack, and get a density of $\frac{\pi}{4}\approx 0.785$

Another alternative is to use a [hexagonal pack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem#Hexagonal_packing_of_circles).  If you have $k$ rows alternating $n$ and $n-1$ you want a sheet $51n \times (1+\frac{k \sqrt{3}}{2})51\ \ $mm, which packs $\lfloor n(k-\frac{1}{2})\rfloor$ circles.  For your case, $n=6, k=12$ will fit $66$ circles in $306 \times 537$ mm, with a packing density of about $0.8205$

For $16$ circles, you could also use a $4 \times 4$ hexagonal pack.  This would require $230=4.5\cdot 51 \times 184\ \ $mm, giving a density of $0.772$, so you could just buy $204 \times 204\ \ $mm and be better off.

Comment: I haven't proven that there is not a more efficient way that doesn't follow the standard packs.  However, those usually just use up the border around a standard pack.  Since you can buy any size you want, it is probably better to choose a standard layout and buy the proper sheet.  I have rounded up to the even mm in my answer.

Comment: The square packing has a constant density.  The hexagonal pack will have a basic waste for a large area, plus waste proportional to the boundary.  So you want the largest sheet (assuming it beats the square pack) because there are more interior points.

Comment: Thanks @Ross, that's exactly the info I needed. I don't quite understand what you've written in this phase though: "$230=4.5\cdot 51 \times 184\ \ $mm", could you please clarify?

Comment: @qftme:  I was just indicating where 230 came from as $4.5\cdot 51$, then that you needed 184 in the other direction.  I agree it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't say *which* websites you've looked at, I don't know whether you've discovered [this one.](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/index.html) Or [this one.](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/junkyard/cover.html) The main thing I get from these pages is that packing is hard, there are no general rules for optimal packings, but there are patterns that often work or are at any rate near-optimal.

Comment: I hadn't seen those particular links @Gerry. Thanks and +1.

Answer (score 0):

The spacing between the circles and the spacing to the edges has been left undefined in your problem. For real-life problems the spacing is non-zero. For Laser-cutting the kerf (width of cut) is generally 0.3mm. 
In addition, generally in that industry 5mm spacing is used, perhaps less.

Using dedicated circle nesting software trying multiple packing arrangements:

For 51mm circles into 530x330 sheet with 0mm inter-part spacing = 67 circles.

For 51mm circles into 530x330 sheet with 5mm inter-part spacing = 54 circles.

For 51mm circles into 204x204 sheet with 0mm inter-part spacing = 16 circles.

For 51mm circles into 204x204 sheet with 5mm inter-part spacing = 11 circles.