# What is the minimum of squares to fit within rectangular box 10 x 16?

Tags: packing-problem

I'm trying to apply circle packing data to a 10 x 16 inch sheet for printing, here: http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/csq.html#Applications

And I want to achieve the least waste by figuring out if I can divide this 10x16 rectangle into squares, the minium of squares beyond the waste from one 10 x 10 square, and calculate the ideal amount of circles.

Basically I'm trying to figure out a rough, yet fairly accurate way to calculate how many designs of given sizes can fit on one 10 x 16 page with minimal waste. I would assume that circles generate less waste than squares, but maybe given the waste of converting it into squares first, squares would be a better way to estimate instead?

Comment: This is really quite confusing. If you are trying to pack squares into a rectangle, why do you mention circles?

Comment: No $16 \times 16$ squares fit in a $10 \times 16$ rectangle, so that would seem to be the minimum.

Comment: A more general question was asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701/how-many-circles-of-a-given-radius-can-be-packed-into-a-given-rectangular-box)  Depending on the size of the circle, it will be more efficient to pack them hexagonally than square pack.

Answer (score 1):

You can do $10+6+4+2+2$ for $5$ squares.  I doubt it can be beat.

Comment: OEIS sequence [A219158](https://oeis.org/A219158) confirms that this is optimal.