# Most dots in a rectangle problem

Tags: geometry, optimization

Consider a rectangle with sides of length **m** and **n**, were **m, n** are integers. We want to place the maximum number of dots inside it however the dots must have a minimum spacing of **1** . Given a minimum spacing **d** which is a factor of both **m** and **n**, and assuming the dots may be placed along the edges of the rectangle, how would one find the maximum number of dots that can be placed inside the rectangle?

I was shown this problem, and tried the naive approach of spacing the dots along both edges by spacing **1** (which I believe would give (**n+1**) and (**m+1**) dots along each side) and multiplied them together. However, apparently we can fit more dots that this in using a different packing arrangement however I don't know where to begin with that kind of problem. Would anyone have any advice?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701/how-many-circles-of-a-given-radius-can-be-packed-into-a-given-rectangular-box) may be relevant. Your question is equivalent to packing circles of radius 1/2 in a rectangle m+1 * n+1.

Comment: Thanks very much